# Linear translations demonstration

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have a book (Algèbre et géométrie linéaires, from Alexei Kostrikin & Youri Manin) in which they provide a Lemma about linear translation which is the following

For $ v_1 + F_1 = v_2 +F_2$ to be true, it is needed and it is sufficient that $F_1 = F_2 = F$ and that $v_1 - v_2 \in F$.

The first part of the demonstration is about showing that it is sufficient, which I understood.
The second part however is a bit confusing for me, and go as follow

Let $v_1 + F_1 = v_2 + F_2$. Lets put $w_0 = v_1 - v_2$. From which we can write $w_0 + F_1 = F_2$ (**So far so good**).
As $0 \in F_2$, we must have $w_0 \in F_1$ (**But I don't understand why**).
Thus as $w_0 + F_1 = F_1$ (As $w_0 \in F_1$), we can say that $F_1 = F_2 = F$ which achieve our demonstration.

What I don't understand is why would the fact that $0$ belong to $F_2$ imply that $w_0$ belong to $F_1$.
Indeed, if I take $v_1 \notin F_1$ and construct a set $F_2$ as follow $v_1 + F_1 = F_2$ then I have $v_1 + F_1 = 0 + F_2$ and $F_1 \neq F_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$w_0 + F_1$ and $F_2$ are equal as sets, that is
$$
\{ w_0 + u : u \in F_1 \} = F_2.
$$
Since $0 \in F_2$, we must also have $0 \in w_0 + F_1$. Thus there exists some $u \in F_1$ such that $0 = w_0 + u$, from which we see that $w_0 = -u \in F_1$.

I am assuming here that $F_1$ and $F_2$ are linear subspaces; your counterexample fails since $v_1 + F_1 = F_2$ is not a subspace (it doesn't contain $0$).